# myBatis Generator - how to generate only select/update/insert/delete SQLs?

Tags: generator, ibatis, mybatis

My config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd" >
<generatorConfiguration >
  <context id="context1" >
    <jdbcConnection driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" userId="system" password="system" ></jdbcConnection>
    <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="pl.domain.model" targetProject="mailsender2" />
    <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="pl.domain.model" targetProject="mailsender2" ></sqlMapGenerator>
    <javaClientGenerator targetPackage="???" targetProject="???" type="XMLMAPPER" />
    <table schema="SYSTEM" tableName="user" domainObjectName="User" enableSelectByExample="false" enableDeleteByExample="false"
                        enableCountByExample="false" enableUpdateByExample="false"  >

    </table>
  </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

How can I generate only simple select/update/insert/delete SQLs? whitout this below?

Mapper.xml

```
<insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="pl.domain.model.User" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Thu Apr 14 13:40:15 CEST 2011.
    -->
    insert into SYSTEM.USER
    <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides="," >
      <if test="userId != null" >
        USER_ID,
      </if>
      <if test="created != null" >
        CREATED,
      </if>
      <if test="firstName != null" >
        FIRST_NAME,
      </if>
      <if test="hash != null" >
        HASH,
      </if>
      <if test="language != null" >
        LANGUAGE,
      </if>
      <if test="lastName != null" >
        LAST_NAME,
```

Answer (score 1):

For supressing the comments, did you try this :

```
<commentGenerator>
    <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true" />
</commentGenerator>
```

Also did you try this:

```
<table tableName="your_table_name_here" domainObjectName="domain_bject_name_here" enableSelectByExample="false" enableDeleteByExample="false" enableCountByExample="false" enableUpdateByExample="false" selectByExampleQueryId="false" selectByPrimaryKeyQueryId="false" modelType="flat">
 </table>
```